# How can a dask worker access the total number of workers currently in the cluster?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

My dask workers need to run `init` code that depends on the number of workers in the cluster. Can workers access such cluster metadata?

Comment: Can the people who voted to close provide a reason why it should be closed as a comment?

Comment: just write the worker and check it

Comment: Comment to those voting to close: this question was very specific:  a dask worker within a dask cluster gettinng information about that cluster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clients can determine the number of workers in a cluster by using the `Client.scheduler_info` function.

```
>>> len(client.scheduler_info()['workers'])
8
```

Any function run within a worker can get a client using the `get_client` function.

```
>>> from dask.distributed import get_client
>>> n = len(get_client.scheduler_info()['workers'])
```

http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.get_client

Although please be aware that this assumes that you're using the dask.distributed scheduler (and so can't use the basic single machine schedulers in the future) and in principle that the number of workers can change over time.